# Setting WinForms ComboBox DataSource does nothing

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

In a fresh WinForms project, I've created a `ComboBox` inside a `UserControl`, populated its `DataSource` property.

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        comboBox1.DataSource = new List<string>() { "a" };
    }
}
```

Took a panel in the main form, added the user control inside the panel.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        panel1.Controls.Add(new UserControl1());
    }
}
```

I see the contents of the `DataSource`:

[image]

Now in the original project, I'm doing the same thing with a `ComboBox`:

```
public ModuleFlasher_915() 
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // Other stuff

    comboBox1.DataSource = new List<string>() { "a" };
}
```

Where `ModuleFlasher_915` is a `UserControl` which gets assigned inside a tab control. When I launch the program, I find the `ComboBox` as empty:

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: It works for me. What code do you use to add the UC to the tab control?

Comment: @Crowcoder: VS designer was used to add the UC to the tab page. It was done by some other developer who no longer works for the company.

Comment: It still works for me when I drag it onto a tab page with the designer. It's a head scratcher.

Answer (score 0):

Silly. `InitializeComponent()` was erroneously called twice in the constructor of the `UserControl` - causing this massacre. Removing the second call resolves the problem.